# Way to get hostname in ansible while only executing on localhost?

Tags: ansible

Is there a built-in that allows for you to grab the hostname of the host you're on, excluding the `inventory_hostname` variable? What I want to do is execute plays on multiple hosts, but they have to be manually ran on each host (security policy, don't worry about it). However, as part of this, we use template variables that require the *actual* hostname of the localhost. Is it possible to acquire this with something other than `inventory_hostname`, since I assume that will just return `localhost`?

Comment: Does the `hostname` shell command return what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure- lots of ways to do that, but this one is friendly to local or remote running:

```
- command: hostname
  register: hostname

- set_fact: 
    actual_hostname: hostname.stdout

# now you can use {{ actual_hostname }} wherever and have 
# the value returned from running hostname on each target host.
```